# Optimizing downloads from Azure Blob Storage with 1000 concurrent users

Tags: azure, blob

I have a question regarding the optimization of Azure blob download speeds. I am looking at having a private container in Azure blob storage with 10000 files of size ~5 MB. Whenever an user wants to download this file, I will be generating a SAS Url for the user to download the file. As of now, I am looking at ~1000 concurrent users downloading various files at any point of time.

I would like to know whether any of the below steps will help me to maintain optimal download speeds for this kind of usage.

1. Will storing the files across different containers help in improving download speeds.
2. Read in the Windows Azure storage team's blog that each storage account has a fixed bandwidth. To offset this , do I need to storing the files across different storage accounts.
3. Is it sufficient to have a single container in a storage account to get the best download speeds for ~1000 concurrent users.
   I
   t will also be great if you can let me know the best practices to achieve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. No. Blobs are the partitions, not the containers.
2. Yes.
3. It depends. The target throughput of a **single** blob is up to 60 MBytes/sec, but since you're talking about 10000 files this shouldn't be a problem (assuming your 1000 concurrent users will download different files). What you'll need to look at is the scalability target of the storage account, where the throughput is up to 3 gigabits per second. This could become an issue if your application grows, but there are a few solutions you can look at:

   - Use multiple storage accounts (maybe one per country, per application, ...). The limit for creating storage accounts is pretty low (it used to be 5 storage accounts per subscription, don't know if this changed), so you'll need to contact Microsoft is you want to use more storage accounts.
   - Think about using the CDN together with blob storage to expose your files. This will improve performance (more throughput) but your users will also download the files much faster since they download from a 'nearby' location.
   - You can also do some caching in your Web Roles (in LocalResources for example, or the Caching Preview, to cache your popular files). But I wouldn't advise on doing this.

This article is a good place to start: [Windows Azure Storage Abstractions and their Scalability Targets](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/05/10/windows-azure-storage-abstractions-and-their-scalability-targets.aspx)